# What is UseDeclareFetch postgresql odbc

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I'm finally testing an older .NET app on windows 10. It runs a dozen sql selects against Postgresql 9.3 (64 bit) using 32 bit 9.03 odbc. The app runs a Select to get a bit of config data Select MyRow, MyName from Config where ConfigID = ? and it returns as expected. Then it runs it again to grab a different id and it fails with ERROR [HY000] No query has been executed with that handle. The sql is syntactically correct and when I run it in a QA it returns as expected. 
I google the error and IBM says to add ;UseDeclareFetch=1 to the connection. I did and the app carries on as it should.

I can't find anything on what ;UseDeclareFetch=1 does and why it suddenly makes a difference in windows 10. I've read https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html but it doesn't say much about what it's for.

Comment: `DECLARE` and `FETCH` suggests it's enabling use of cursors.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Thank you. I ran through the odbc logs. 

I don't understand how turning a cursor on in the driver helps bring back 1 record in windows 10. 

It's easy enough to just change the conString but I'd like a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UseDeclareFetch=1` changes the behavior of the underlying libpq PostgreSQL Library when using UnixODBC to enable the "Single Row Mode" as described [in the single row mode documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html).

With this mode set, each fetch results in a client-server round trip and fetches one row from the cursor to the client.

Without this mode (the default is to *not* use `UseDeclareFetch`) then the entire result set from the cursor is pushed to client memory before the first fetch is returned. This reduces network usage, but increases (sometimes greatly) the amount of client RAM required for a cursor result set.

So, if client RAM is limited, you might want to set `UseDeclareFetch`, but beware of the potential network latency issues for performance if you do use it.